# I need to update R version on linux

Tags: android, r, linux

My work is on mobile phone it is with android system .. I download linux and R vesion 2.15.2 on it put the problem is that many packages doesn't work in this version .. I ned to upgrate this version to 3.3.2 ..help me and thanks alot

Comment: Please update your question with the errors that you see.

Comment: 2.15.2 is quite old. It is also not a maintenance version. I might go with maintenance versions if it is particularly difficult to upgrade your version. 3.1.3 or 3.2.5 are the two most recent. Newly released packages are built for these for an extended period of time.

Comment: I need a commands on R or on linux i can update R version by it from 2.15.2 to 3.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you run the following Linux commands in a terminal session?

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'

// Add the keys.
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9
gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -

// Install R
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install r-base
```